# Ignore tf-idf using a common query

Tags: elasticsearch, tf-idf

I like to ignore the tf-idf using a common query.

Why isn't this possible with constant_score?

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/test/my_type/_search?pretty=1' -d 
'{
    "query":{
        "common":{
            "de":{
                "constant_score":{
                    "query":"word",
                    "cutoff_frequency":0.001,
                    "minimum_should_match":{
                        "low_freq":"-60%"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

I get this error:

```
QueryParsingException[[test] [common] query does not support [constant_score]]
```